# CSS3 border radius + different border width, ugly transition

Tags: css

I got another tricky CSS3 situation that I'm breaking my head on. I'm styleing a form with CSS to have a 10px border on the sides and a 12px border on the bottom, in combination with a 15px border radius.

Unfortunately, the point where the 12px and the 10px borders meet the transition is not gradual but there's a 2px chunk sticking out of the inside of the border. Example (sizes magnified for clarity):

http://jsfiddle.net/LnKND/1/

Any idea how to fix this using only css and no extra elements? Or is this just the way it's rendered currently and should I find another solution?

Comment: What browser are you using? I don't think I'm able to replicate the issue you're having using firefox 3.6/ie9

Comment: Your jsfiddle example has an error - `-moz-border-radius: 0 0 25px 15p;` is missing the `x` on the end of `15px`. This means it doesn't work in Firefox.

Comment: by the way, slightly off-topic, but if you want border radius in IE6/7/8, check out http://css3pie.com

Comment: Typo was in the example only, not in my original source. I'm using chrome, and hadn't optimized for other browsers yet. I know about css3pie, but thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
    border-bottom-left-radius:10px 20px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:10px 20px;
```

reference : http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-border-radius

---

for mozilla use

```
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft
```

if you want, although it handles the issue automatically (*if you fix the typo p to px in the example*).

reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/border-bottom-right-radius

Comment: This seems to fix it, but I'm left with a square inner border. I'd like both the inside and the outside rounded, which only works if the border radius is bigger than the border width.. so that leaves me with a problem :P

Comment: @Stephan, looks like it is a chrome *buggy* implementation. Here is a huge showcase http://muddledramblings.com/table-of-css3-border-radius-compliance for more info.

Comment: Whoa, interesting link. Thanks a bunch.